# VBA code to separate cell string and copy it to next rows in a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a VBA code that will:

copy Column A data in sheet 1 to Column A in sheet 2, and for each specific row in sheet 1: if row i column C has text separated by commas then copy each value separate by a comma  and create new rows in sheet 2 to have all of those values in consecutive rows while copying the value of column A (only) from sheet one with it as well and leave the rest of the columns blank while this occurs.

here is an example of sheet 1

[image: example of sheet 1]

here is how it should be translated in sheet 2

[image: example of sheet 2]

I am kinda new to VBA but I have been researching and trying different codes to represent what I am looking for, but nothing I could have find or created worked for me so far.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: You could look into using the `Split` function with a new array, e.g. `myArray = Split(myString, ",")` where `myString` would equal "25,28,39" - this would give you an array with 3 elements, 25, 28 and 39!

Comment: On top of that you'd just need a row counter, one main loop to go through all rows and another loop to go through the array each time you fill it with the cell contents via the split.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small sample of setting an array based on a string (which you could get from cell contents) then looping through the array and placing the values of the array in to a row for each. Hopefully you can build on this to fit your needs:

```
Sub loopingz()

Dim i As Long
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim myArray() As String
Dim myString As String

myString = "25,26,39"
myArray = Split(myString, ",")
currentRow = 1


For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Range("A" & currentRow).Value2 = myArray(i)
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Next i

End Sub
```